# Qt: joinMulticastGroup for all interface

Tags: c++, qt, multicast

In Windows I have two physical interface. On each interface set two IP address: IPv4 and IPv6.
The following code doesn't correct working in this configuration: **joinMulticastGroup** return **true** only for first interface and for next interface **joinMulticastGroup** return **false**.

But, if I turn off IPv6 on Windows interfaces this code working.

Help me understand.

```c
QUdpSocket udpSocket;
QHostAddress groupAddress;

groupAddress = QHostAddress("239.255.255.250");
udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 1900,
                QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);

QList<QNetworkInterface> mListIfaces = QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces();

for (int i = 0; i < mListIfaces.length(); ++i) {
    bool rez = udpSocket.joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress, mListIfaces.at(i));
    qDebug() << rez;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was recently dealing with multicast and Qt, and this problem seems to still exist with Qt 5.6 and Win7.

The problem is that `joinMulticastGroup()` uses the first address of the interface without checking if it's IPV4 or IPV6 (even if you use AnyIpv4 in bind).

This issue is not fixed in the official Qt release, but the proposed patch works for me:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27641

Comment: VERY helpful to force me to understand the QNetworkInterface a bit more clearly.  Solved the inconsistent multicast functionality completely.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading isValid() and eventually

`QNetworkInterface::CanMulticast` from interface flags and check 
`QNetworkInterface::IsRunning` and does not have 
`QNetworkInterface::IsLoopBack`.

Furthermore check for associated IPv4 in `addresses()` with `QNetworkAddressEntry::ip().protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol`

Comment: do not broadcast if any of the named flags() is not set. Also do only multicast on IPv4 if an IPv4 Address is associated.

Comment: For all interface set CanMulticast, IsValid, IsRunning. Not in this case. `QNetworkAddressEntry::ip().protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol` and what is it for me? First and second interface have IPv4 address and IPv6 address. joinMulticastGroup join only first interface. But if interfaces not have IPv6 address joinMulticastGroup join both.

Comment: Your code tries to join on all interfaces. But ``QUdpSocket::joinMulticastGroup(const QHostAddress & groupAddress)`` joins on the default interface chosen by the OS (from the docs). Check the socket error for specific problems: ``qDebug()<<QUdpSocket::errorString();`` MultiCast is only valid for IPv4

Comment: Sry for wrong comment, given with iface you can join on different ifaces, but those still must have a valid ipv4 and the named flags must be read as true.

Comment: This config for my interface: `qDebug() << mListIfaces.at(0);` QNetworkInterface(name = "{78667AE0-BF4C-4750-B915-FF325C4E857C}", hardware address = "08:00:27:A6:7B:6C", flags = IsUp IsRunning CanBroadcast CanMulticast , entries = ((address = QHostAddress("fe80::dd05:1c01:bf86:caa%13") , netmask = QHostAddress("ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::") ) ,  (address = QHostAddress("192.168.1.238") , netmask = QHostAddress("255.255.255.0") , broadcast = QHostAddress("192.168.1.255") ) )  )

Comment: `qDebug() << mListIfaces.at(1);` QNetworkInterface(name = "{F0B59671-89F8-477E-BDA4-645F2BBC425C}", hardware address = "08:00:27:57:10:F7", flags = IsUp IsRunning CanBroadcast CanMulticast , entries = ((address = QHostAddress("fe80::7153:c123:14ce:17cd%11") , netmask = QHostAddress("ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::") ) ,  (address = QHostAddress("192.168.38.237") , netmask = QHostAddress("255.255.255.0") , broadcast = QHostAddress("192.168.38.255") ) )  )

Comment: In this configuration join only zero interface. If disable IPv6 in first interface then join both interface: zero and first. WTF?

Comment: `bool rez = udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress, mListIfaces.at(i)); qDebug() << udpSocket->errorString();` This code everytime printed "Unknown error".

Comment: is ``rez`` false at all (errorString() should return a known error if rez is false)? This sounds like it does actually join.

Comment: No, rez set in True for zero interface, for next interfaces it set in False. But, if I disable IPv6 in all interfaces then rez set in True for all interfaces.

Comment: as soon rez is false, you should have an errorString() other than Unknown error

Comment: I understand this. But errorString() everytime return "Unknown error".

Answer (score 1):

So for a working example that may help others, find below what works in Win10 Pro 64 bit with Qt 5.15.0 MinGW.  Essentially, get a list of the interfaces, then loop through those interfaces and throw out the ones which should not be used by testing the flags and the `isValid()` function.

In my example, I only want to join the IP address of my initial QUdpSocket bind call.  That if/then filter is optional if you prefer and results in joining all valid addresses on that interface.

```
// Windows is weird
QList<QNetworkInterface> interfaces = QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces();
// Try the multicast UDP socket for SA first
saMC = new QUdpSocket(this);
saMC->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);
//saMC->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, 1);
connect(saMC, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &Commander::handleDatagram, Qt::UniqueConnection);
QHostAddress toBind("192.168.0.51");
if(saMC->bind(toBind, 6969, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress|QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint))
{
    foreach(QNetworkInterface interface, interfaces)
    {
        //qDebug()<<"interface:"<<interface.isValid()<<interface.flags();
        QNetworkInterface::InterfaceFlags iflags = interface.flags();
        if(interface.isValid() && !iflags.testFlag(QNetworkInterface::IsLoopBack) && iflags.testFlag(QNetworkInterface::CanMulticast) && iflags.testFlag(QNetworkInterface::IsRunning))
        {

            QList<QNetworkAddressEntry> addressEntries = interface.addressEntries();
            for (int i = 0; i < addressEntries.length(); i++) {
                QNetworkAddressEntry ae = addressEntries.at(i);
                if(ae.ip() == toBind)
                {
                    bool ok = false;
                    if (ae.ip().protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol)
                    {
                        ok = saMC->joinMulticastGroup(QHostAddress("239.2.3.1"), interface);
                    }
                    if(ok)
                    {
                        qDebug()<<"SA bound...join mc group:"<<ae.ip();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        qDebug()<<"SA bound...interface unsuitable for Multicast:"<<ae.ip();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    qDebug()<<"SA multicast socket unable to bind...."<<saMC->errorString();
}
```